# Template and operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was going through code... I found a template class which is declared as shown below.

```
template <class T> 
class tType 
{
public:
    T value;
    T operator=(T val){ value = val; return value; }
    tType<T> operator=(tType<T> &val){ value = val.value; return *this; }
    operator T(){ return value; }
};
```

I also found operator overloaded like below...

********1********

```
template <class T>
bool operator==(T& val, tType<T>& tval) { return(val == tval.value); }
```

I didn't understand when the above operator gets called... cos when I did...

```
int main(void)
{
    tType<int> x;
    x = 5;
    if (5 == x)
    {
        cout << "Both are equal" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above said operator was not getting called... and was still working... I also wrote below code for testing and the below code snippet is getting called...

```
template<class T>
bool operator==(int x, tType<T>& val) { return (x == val.value); }
```

I wasn't to know who to call *******1*******

Answer (score 3):

It's right that the reason your `operator==` isn't called is because of the missing `const` identifier. In this case, the literal `5` is unable to be passed as a *variable reference* for the paramater `T& val`. But, that's not quite the whole story.

As you point out, the code still compiles and runs even though the function isn't being called.

The reason your code still works is because of the [**conversion operator**](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=24): `operator T(){ return value; }`.

A conversion operator allows implicit casts from one type to another. For example:

```
struct Number {
    Number(int x) : value(x) { }
    operator int() { return value; }
private:
    int value;
};

int main() {

    Number n(5);
    int x = n;          // 5  -- operator int() at work
    int y = n + x;      // 10 -- operator int() at work
    Number z = x + y;   // 15 -- Number(int) at work

    cout << x <<" "<< y <<" "<< z << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `operator int()` allows `n` to convert into an `int` for assignment to `x` and to convert to an `int` for addition with `x` (the resultant `int` is then assigned to `y`), while the unary constructor `Number(int)` allows the result of `x + y` to convert back to a `Number`.

In your code, `5 == x` still compiles because the `tType<int>` `x` is converted into an `int` via its `operator int()` member function, and then that resultant `int` is compared against the literal `5`.

---

However, this probably isn't a very good design for a class. For example, in order to compare two `tType<T>`s, a cast into `T` will be required for one of them.

```
template <class T>
bool operator==(const T& val, const tType<T>& tval) {
    cout << "operator==(const T& val, const tType<T>& tval) was called." << endl;
    return(val == tval.value);
}

//...

cout << ( tType<int>() == tType<int>() ) << endl;   // calls operator==(const T&, const tType<T>&)
```

You would rather have an `operator==` for two `tType<T>`s.

Another **even bigger problem** is that this is not symmetric:

```
cout << (x1 == 5) << endl;      // calls operator==(int,int)   (the built-in function)
```

Yikes!

---

To address all of these, there is a very straightforward design solution. This is taken from Scott Meyers' book [`Effective C++ Third Edition`](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) (a phenomenal book).

Instead of converting back to a `T` with a conversion operator, the class should include an implicit unary constructor to convert `T`'s up to `tType<T>`s, and should declare exactly one `operator==` for `tType<T>`s:

```
template <class T> 
class tType 
{
public:
    tType<T>(const T &val) : value(val) { }       // unary non-explicit constructor
    tType<T> operator=(const tType<T> &val){ value = val.value; return *this; } // only need one

    T val() { return value; }
private:
    T value;          // Note also value is private (encapsulation)
};

template<class T>
bool operator==(const tType<T>& a, const tType<T>& b) { return ( a.val() == b.val() ); }
```

The important changes:

1. Added a constructor that takes a single value; this allows converting `T`s into `tType`s.
2. Removed the assignment operator taking `T`s (because now we can convert them to `tType`s.
3. Only have one equality operator and it takes two `const tType<T>&`s, meaning `operator==` can handle any combination of `T`s and `tType<T>`s (or, even better, anything convertible into either of those).

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator attempts to bind non-`const` references to the arguments - values like "5" are not amenable to that... the parameters should be `const`:

```
template <class T>
bool operator==(const T& val, const tType<T>& tval) { return val == tval.value; }
```

As that will still only support e.g. `5 == my_tType` and not `my_tType == 5`, you may want to also provide...

```
template <class T>
bool operator==(const tType<T>& tval, const T& val) { return val == tval.value; }
```

...and for `my_tType1 == my_tType2`...

```
template <class T>
bool operator==(const tType<T>& tval1, const tType<T>& tval2) {
    return tval1.value == tval2.value; }
```

This gives you maximum control of the comparisons.  An alternative is to allow implicit construction of a `tType` from a `T` argument, but implicit construction and conversion operators are generally discouraged these days - they can lead to ambiguities and accidental creation of temporaries that can be hard to debug.  A topic for another question....

When you say "The above said operator was not getting called... and was still working" - what was actually happening was that `tType::operator T()` (which returns `value;`) was being implicitly called, returning an `int` that could be compared - as an `int` - to `5`.  Hence - you had a comparison, but not using the custom `operator==`.  This is a normal result of finding the "best match" for a function call.

Answer (score 1):

Change the function

```
template <class T>
bool operator==(T& val, tType<T>& tval) { return(val == tval.value); }
```

to

```
template <class T>
bool operator==(T const& val, tType<T> const& tval) { return(val == tval.value); }
```

or

```
template <class T>
bool operator==(T val, tType<T> tval) { return(val == tval.value); }
```

Your function was not getting called since `5` cannot be converted to `int&`.